# Automatic spaces before and after inserted string

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I'm trying to copy a text from `EditText` and then insert it in `EditText`, it automatically adds spaces before and after inserted string. For example, `EditText` contains "**TEST TEST TEST**", I copy **TEST** and then after inserting it "**TE**(here)**ST TEST TEST**" I get "**TE TEST ST TEST TEST**".

Here is my EditText

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
</EditText>
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: This is an Eclipse IDE issue. You must be editing in Graphical Layout. Try editing in XML.

Comment: I tried to add EditText in XML, but there is still the same problem when I run my app.